# How to retain date stamp while copying to another PC

Tags: 12.04, ssh, krusader, timestamp

Similarly to [How to maintain a file's 'last modified' date ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312172/how-to-maintain-a-files-last-modified-date) I need to retain the date while copying the file by Krusader or in a 'Home Folder' window to another PC connected by SSH. Is it possible?

Comment: Are both machines running Linux and using a Linux file system?

Comment: Both machines run Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I just realized what `krusader` is. My answer is for doing it manually, don't know if it's possible with `krusader`. Is that a deal breaker for you?

Comment: I am just coming to Ubuntu from Windows XP. I am used to Total Commander; I'd be very glad if I can use Krusader this way; at a single PC it works, also with flashes.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the `-p` option to `scp`. As explained in `man scp`:

```
 -p      Preserves modification times, access times, and modes from the
         original file.
```

So, just run

```
scp source_file user@host:/remote/path/file
```

Comment: Is it possible to set generally in Krusader? I do not see such setting there.

Comment: @TomasPeceny I'm playing with it now. How exactly are you connecting to the remote directory? Are you using the `fish` protocol through `krusadser`'s "Net connection" menu option?

Comment: Yes, I am using the fish protocol through krusadser's "Net connection" menu option.

Comment: @TomasPeceny no, sorry. As far as I can tell this isn't possible with `krusader`. Your best bet would be to use a terminal and issue the command above.

Comment: Should I connect the PCs by samba? I have tried it, but the connection worked only from PC1 to PC2, not from PC2 to PC1. I had similar problem in Windows XP, but it may be connected with antivirus AVG firewall setting and I need not solve it. I think it is not due to hardware: after interchanging ethernet cables the connection worked again from PC1 to PC2, not from PC2 to PC1. Maybe the solution for me is to use user commands if they can be done by Krusader as they are done with the Total Commander.

Comment: @TomasPeceny huh? No, why smb? They're two Linux boxes, if anything you should use NFS. In any case, you don't need to mount anything. Just open a terminal and run `scp -p source user@target:/path/to/target` and that will copy the file `source` to `target` on the remote machine, keeping the same modification date. Mounting the directories locally would not help you use krusader for what you want. You would have the same problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14437/discussion-between-tomas-peceny-and-terdon)

Comment: Up to now I use Krusader as I have described; because the PC stands yet at my table beside the other PC aimed as a backup one, I copy the files using the destination PC. This way, the date stamps are retained. I hope that in future I will be able to modify slightly the sources and translate them. In the meantime, is it useful to suggest it to the Krusader authors? Could you yield me a direct contact? Date stamps retaining is not the only improvement I see as generally useful. Or should I first let the improvement themes to be discussed here? By what form; as a question? Thanks!

Comment: @TomasPeceny no, not here, the authors are unlikely to see it. There is almost certainly a bug tracking system for krusader or you could submid to the KDE maintainers. I've never used it though so I can't tell you any more than that, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, I have proposed it to the Krusader developers forum https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/krusader-devel/hxxQXYYTguo .

Comment: I begin trying to adjust it myself. Please look at my questions http://askubuntu.com/questions/485242/an-introduction-to-translating-and-debugging-source-code and at the example linked from it. Would you give me a tip for such a general introduction? Thanks!

Comment: @TomasPeceny I wish you the best of luck with it but I'm afraid that kind of open ended question is too broad for the Q&A format of the stackexchange sites. There are [many IDEs](http://askubuntu.com/q/48299/85695) available for Linux and C is the language of choice but I can't really give you any more than that.