# How to update the multiple files without changing file date?

Tags: find, sed, sh

I have replaced word '`merchant`' to '`capital`' in files founded in the current directory using following command:

```
find * -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/merchant/capital/g' {} \;
```

but above command will modify the file date also, is there any way to stop file modification date?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use ls to know the time stamp then after  you finish the find  comand use  touch command to modify the time stamp back again

Comment: Thank you @FatMind can you give the syntax how to write?

Comment: I use the mobile now ... you can check this question it will help http://askubuntu.com/questions/62492/how-can-i-change-the-date-modified-created-of-a-file

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a clear solution for you.

But as a workaround solution.

Get the modification date of a file

```
stat file.txt | grep Modify
```

Now After completing what you did restore the previous modification date

```
touch  -m -t [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]
```

he following explains the above format:

- CC – Specifies the first two digits of the year
- YY – Specifies the last two digits of the year. If the value of the
  YY is between 70 and 99, the value of the CC digits is assumed to be
- If the value of the YY is between 00 and 37, the value of the CC digits is assumed to be 20. It is not possible to set the date beyond
  January 18, 2038.
- MM – Specifies the month
- DD – Specifies the date
- hh – Specifies the hour
- mm – Specifies the minute
- SS – Specifies the seconds

**For example:** changind modification date of a file of mine called url.txt

```
stat url.txt | grep Modify
```

output

```
Modify: 2015-05-04 09:42:28.148281881 +0300
```

change modification to 04/05/2016 20:05:04

```
touch -m -t 201605042005.04 url.txt
```

Get sure that works

```
stat url.txt | grep Modify
```

output

```
Modify: 2016-05-04 20:05:04.000000000 +0300
```