# Overwrite FS properties with the EXIF props

Tags: filesystem, rename, date

I currently have some files that are working and displaying the correct properties from the FS. But some are showing incorrectly when trying to order by date. As the date is showing as "Unknown"

For example:
[image]

I cannot order by Date as I have a few scricts that will merge all these files into one for me. But with the dates not working. The other is all "messed up"

So is it possible to overwrite certain FS properties from the film with the properties help in the File EXIF?

Files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1IMVgOM6M1OTLL2HTcKOGp6Tyvinta4K7?usp=sharing
Of course, I cannot test this easily as when I download the file to my machine, the new time stamps are shown:
[image]

Comment: You question is not clear, but you can use the `identify` command from ImageMagick-ims6.q16(1) suite of tools and get the "`%[EXIF:DateTime]`" from the EXIF info in the file. Then you can use the `touch` command to change the modification date/time of the file.

Comment: This is not easily achieved. Linux will only save timestamps for file access and file modification by default. Not file creation.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity in the question chaps. Well I would be looking to edit the files props after it is saved and transferred to my Machine. Via an SH script. Alternatively I could update my sort to do it from the file and not the FS? `find . -type f -name '*.MP4' -printf "file '$PWD/%p'\n" | sort`

Comment: Actually I am using `ls -1v -tr`