# How to rsync **photos** from a specific date forward, namely from the date on which the photo was taken (e.g., exif:DateTime)?

Tags: rsync, photo-management, exif

Starting with [find and rsync?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87022/30271) and [How to rsync files / folders from a specific date forward?](https://serverfault.com/a/642231/632370), how to rsync **photos** from a specific date, namely **from the date on which the photo was taken** (i.e., from the photo's meta data, i.e. **EXIF**, e.g., exif:DateTime, which may well differ from the file's "<strike>last modified date</strike>") forward?

One idea would be to make use of `identify -verbose IMG_20200430_113445.jpg | grep -i date` and `exif:DateTime` within, another would be to use `exiftool` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48582185/only-get-datetimeoriginal-with-exiftool) for that. Maybe this and elements of the two Q&A's quoted above would work?

---

That is, combining the ideas from the two above quoted Q&A's (and perhaps also [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62492/how-can-i-change-the-date-modified-created-of-a-file/329463#comment2544775_329463)) with this

`identify -verbose IMG_20200430_113445.jpg | grep -i date`, returning `exif:DateTime`

or this

`exiftool -DateTimeOriginal IMG_20200430_113445.jpg`

might be "the" way...

---

See also:

- [rsync](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/rsync.1.html)
- [find](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/find.1posix.html)
- [identify](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/identify.im6.1.html)
- [exiftool](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/exiftool.1p.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Backup photos (*.jpg's) shot after a certain date

The following approach uses **[rsync](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/rsync.1.html)** and **[exiftool](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/exiftool.1p.html)** (and ***not*** [find](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/find.1posix.html) and [identify](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/identify.im6.1.html)).

### Filter

To get a first idea of the number of files which meet the **filter**'s criteria one may start off with

```
exiftool -progress -if '$DateTimeOriginal ge "2012:01:01"' -p '$FileName' *.jpg
```

### Dry-run

Next, one may do a "**dry run**", to see what *would* be copied in the next step, with

```
rsync -n -aPh --ignore-existing --stats --info=progress2 --files-from=<(exiftool -if '$DateTimeOriginal ge "2015:01:01"' -p '$FileName' *.jpg) /source/ /dest/
```

### Sync

Finally, one may perform the actual "**copy**" operation, by removing `-n` from the above line, like so:

```
rsync -aPh --ignore-existing --stats --info=progress2 --files-from=<(exiftool -if '$DateTimeOriginal ge "2015:01:01"' -p '$FileName' *.jpg) /source/ /dest/
```

---

Related links:

- [<()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443085/what-does-command-args-mean-in-the-shell) and [What exactly is <() in bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1059781/what-exactly-is-in-bash-and-in-zsh)
- [command substitution `($(...))` vs. process substitution `(<(...))`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393349/difference-between-subshells-and-process-substitution)
- [`/dev/fd/*`--- How process substitution is implemented in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124947/how-process-substitution-is-implemented-in-bash)
- [exiftool.org - Filter Photos with a date range of the DateTimeOriginal](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=8279.0)
- [geeksforgeeks.org/perl-comparing-scalars](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perl-comparing-scalars/) (**ge** ~ **g**reater than or **e**qual to)
- [exiftool.org - Replacing Shell "Find" and Exiftool with an Exiftool-only search](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=7771.0)
- [exiftool.org - Find and update files where filename and datetimeoriginal do not match](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=8788.0)
- [`-fast[NUM]`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/exiftool.1p.html) may yield some performance gains

Answer (score 1):

This is the command I used to copy my 2022 files to my photo subdirectory.
Iphone mounted at /mnt/iPhone and files are in /DCIM/103APPLE
Destination is my photos, with different folders for each year.

```
find /mnt/iPhone/DCIM/103APPLE -name "*.*" -newermt "2022-01-01" ! -newermt "2023-01-01"  -print0 | rsync -aruvlP /mnt/iPhone/DCIM/103APPLE/  /mnt/data/Pictures/All2022/Fred/103APPLE
```

I do not normally use  second date as year to date.

```
find /mnt/iPhone/DCIM/103APPLE -name "*.*" -newermt "2023-01-01 00:00:00" -print0 | rsync -aruvlP /mnt/iPhone/DCIM/103APPLE/  /mnt/data/Pictures/All2023/Fred/103APPLE
```

Comment: That's what the two quoted Q&A's already cover; but I'm not after the `newermt`, but rather the date the photo was taken, which may well be different.