# How to remove all files with a pattern except the recently created file

Tags: ls

How to remove all files with a pattern except the recently created file

```
ls -l
total 655748
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty 120579643 May 10 19:59 2023_05_10.jetty.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty 115205809 May 11 19:59 2023_05_11.jetty.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty 102921116 May 12 19:59 2023_05_12.jetty.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  85266768 May 13 19:59 2023_05_13.jetty.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  97032182 May 14 19:59 2023_05_14.jetty.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty 117095164 May 15 19:59 2023_05_15.jetty.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 jetty jetty  33339025 May 16 04:13 2023_05_16.jetty.log
```

Comment: Please explain how to identify the pattern so that no mistakes will be made! In your example it is simple: remove all files except the newest one, but I guess there can be other files in the directory: what names would they have? How to tell them apart from those that should be removed?

Comment: Related: [Remove all files within directory older than the most recently added ten files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930694/remove-all-files-within-directory-older-than-the-most-recently-added-ten-files)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you actually need the file creation time, you'd need [Ubuntu 20.10 or newer](https://askubuntu.com/a/980750/158442), as before that GNU coreutils tools couldn't access the file creation time.

But on 20.10 and newer, you can use:

```
find some/directory -type f -exec stat --format '%W' {} \; -printf "%p\0" |
  sort -zn |
  sed -z 's/^[0-9.]*\n//; $d' |
  xargs -r0 echo rm --
```

- The entire pipeline uses null-delimited data, which is the safest way of handling filenames
- [GNU `find` can't access the birth time on Linux](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?61327) yet, so we use `stat` to print the birth time, and then use `find` to print the filename with the null character to delimit it
- Then we sort the data numerically (so based on the creation time)
- Then we remove the birth time prefix leaving us with just the filenames, and also remove the last line, which would be the newest file
- Then we use `xargs` with `rm` to delete all these files. The command above uses `echo rm` to show the commands that will be run — remove the `echo` to actually run `rm` and delete the files.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by utilizing the `ls` option `-t` which lists the files in the order of most recently modified. With the option `-p` we can exclude any subdirectories that may reside in the current directory.

With my testing, this would then look like:

```
[11:55:08] /home/jaska/src/foo/> ls -tp 
baz.log  bar/  bar.log  foo.log  foo  barbaz
```

Next we need to use `grep` to get rid of the unwanted directory:

```
[11:55:16] /home/jaska/src/foo/> ls -tp | grep -v '/$'                          
baz.log
bar.log
foo.log
foo
barbaz
```

Then we have to declare the pattern, again using `grep` to do so:

```
[11:55:28] /home/jaska/src/foo/> ls -tp | grep -v '/$' | grep \.log             
baz.log
bar.log
foo.log
```

Because they're in the correct order already, we use `tail` to drop a certain amount from the bottom up:

```
[11:55:21] /home/jaska/src/foo/> ls -tp | grep -v '/$' | grep \.log | tail -n +2
bar.log
foo.log
```

And then finally we delete the specified files:

```
[11:52:05] /home/jaska/src/foo/> ls -tp | grep -v '/$' | grep \.log | tail -n +2 | xargs -I {} rm -- {}
[12:01:59] /home/jaska/src/foo/> ll
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 jaska jaska 4096 May 16 11:53 bar/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jaska jaska    0 May 16 11:48 barbaz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jaska jaska    0 May 16 11:54 baz.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jaska jaska    0 May 16 11:50 foo
```

You may notice that the only remaining .log file is not listed in the latest output, as it was the most recently modified.

To recap, the full command to use is:

```
ls -tp | grep -v '/$' | grep \.log | tail -n +2 | xargs -I {} rm -- {}
```

You may want to tinker with the second `grep` part to fit just certain log files, but from the listing you gave us, that should be sufficient.

Credits go to, and full explanation to all parts can be found at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785/delete-all-but-the-most-recent-x-files-in-bash

Comment: Nice use of `ls -p` to identify and later weed out any directories! I would not bother with `grep \.log`, though, and would instead do `ls -tp *.log`. It may also be pertinent to us `ls -c` rather than `ls -t`, to ensure the files are listed in order of creation time, rather than modification time.

In OP's specific case, a shorter working version is `ls -c *.log | tail +2 | xargs rm`.

Comment: Very good recommendations, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#### Note # 1

What you actually see in the output of `ls -l` is the file's last modification date and **not** the creation date.

`find` has pattern matching(*globbing*) like `-name "*jetty.log"` and it has `-mtime` for days modified ... So, for example:

```
find . -mtime +0 -type f -name "*jetty.log"
```

To find matching files modified more than 24 hours ago ... 1 for 48 hours and so on.

And it has `-mmin` for minutes modified ... So, for example:

```
find . -mmin +10 -type f -name "*jetty.log"
```

To find matching files modified more than 10 minutes ago.

And it has the `-delete` action to delete matched files ... So, for example:

```
find . -mtime +9 -type f -name "*jetty.log" -delete
```

To find matching files modified more than 10 days ago and delete them.

You can restrict the search to the current folder's first level only by adding `-maxdepth 1` to prevent matching files in sub-directories.

#### Note # 2

I noticed that your filenames begin with a date pattern e.g. `2923_05_10...` ... If that is consistent and you want to match by those dates, then you can use pattern matching like, for example:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "2023_05_1[0-4].jetty.log"
```

To match files with `2023_05_10` to `2023_05_14` in their names.

As these date patterns in the filenames can be easily parsed into actual dates, you can also do that in `bash` like, for example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

days=5 # Set the number of days from now for a date to be considered as recent

for f in *.jetty.log
  do
    f1="${f%%.*}"
    f1="${f1//_/-}"
    fd="$(date -d "$f1" '+%s')"
    td="$(date -d "- $days days" '+%s')"
    [ -f "$f" ] && [ "$fd" -lt "$td" ] && echo rm -- "$f"
    done
```

To match and print files with dates in their names older than 5 days ... If the output is what you want, then remove `echo` and re run it again to delete those files.

#### Note # 3

If what you mean is actually the creation/birth date of the file, then you can do that in `bash` with for example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

days=5 # Set the number of days from now for a date to be considered recent

for f in *.jetty.log
  do
    cd="$(stat -c '%w' "$f")"
    fcd="$(date -d "$cd" '+%s')"
    td="$(date -d "- $days days" '+%s')"
    [ -f "$f" ] && [ "$fcd" -lt "$td" ] && echo rm -- "$f"
    done
```

To match and print files with creation date older than 5 days ... If the output is what you want, then remove `echo` and re run it again to delete those files.

This one, however, requires a recent kernel as the support for `stat` accessing date of birth was absent in older kernels ... Please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1460398) for more explanation about this.

#### Note # 4

Simplify your life with `bash` functions to complement missing system-tools functionalities ... For example, this `bash` function:

```bash
function rm_old {

lfcd=0
for f in *
  do
    if [ -f "$f" ]
      then
        fcd="$(stat -c '%w' "$f")"
        fcd="$(date -d "$fcd" '+%s')"
        if [ "$fcd" -gt "$lfcd" ]
          then
            todelete+=("${tokeep[@]}")
            tokeep=("$f")
            lfcd="$fcd"
           elif [ "$fcd" -eq "$lfcd" ]
             then
               tokeep+=("$f")
            else
              todelete+=("$f")
            fi
        fi
    done

echo "These files will be DELETED:"
printf '\e[4;31m%s\e[0m\n' "${todelete[@]}"
echo "This/These file(s) will be KEPT:"
printf '\e[4;32m%s\e[0m\n' "${tokeep[@]}"
read -p "Confirm Y(Yes)/N(No)" answer
case "$answer" in

  Yes|yes|YES|Y|y)
    [ "${#todelete[@]}" -gt 0 ] && rm -- "${todelete[@]}" || echo "Exiting ..."
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Aborting ..."
    ;;
  esac

unset answer
unset todelete
unset tokeep
unset fcd
unset lfcd

}
```

Will keep only the last created file/files in the current working directory and delete the rest.